# mexfunction Inputs confusion

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am new in mex type programming, basically I am writting my first mexfunction, and I am encountering a silly problems. I attach a part of my code:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

        int mrows,ncols;
        mrows = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
        ncols = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

        int numElements = ncols;
        size_t size = numElements * sizeof(float);

        float *in_A = (float *)mxMalloc(size);

        float *in_B = (float *)malloc(size);

        float *out_C = (float *)malloc(size);

        if (in_A == NULL || in_B == NULL ||out_C == NULL)
        {
            mexErrMsgTxt("Failed to allocate host vectors!\n");
        }

        if (nrhs != 2) 
            mexErrMsgTxt("Two inputs required. A vector and a multiplier");
        if (nlhs != 1) 
            mexErrMsgTxt("One output required. The resulting vector");


        in_A = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
            in_B = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

        //printf("%f %f\n", in_A[2], in_A[1]);
        //mexPrintf("%d\n", prhs[1]);

           plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(mrows,ncols, mxREAL);
           out_C = (float *)mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

            add_two_vectors(in_A,in_B,out_C);

}
```

The function `add_two_vectors(float* A,float* B,float* C)` is working but when I am running the script inside a mexfunction I have a problem. Also it reads correctly the *nrows* and *ncols* variables. The problem is that I can not insert the correct inputs in the function. I have tried to print some of the vector elements but it prints different elements than the input vector elements. I am calling mexfunction like that `a = addVector([1.1 2.2 355],[2.5 45 5.5])`. Can someone enlighten me??

Thank you in advance.

PS: Matlab 2011a, VS 2010, Win 7 64x.

Comment: The code has a number of problems: the `malloc` calls are leaking memory and not necessary at all, you should use `mxGetData` instead of `mxGetPr`, `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` will create `double` matrices not `single`. You should include some validation at the beginning of the MEX-file to make sure the inputs are of the expected type (`single` I assume). Also it would be helpful to show us the `add_two_vectors` function

Comment: The essence of the problem is that `mxGetPr` gives a `double*`, which cannot be cast to `float*` without the read/written floats being misinterpreted.  To read/write other data types, use `mxGetPr` *but still make sure you read/write the correct data type for the underlying buffer* to avoid misinterpreting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give an example how I would implement such a function:

#### add_vectors.cpp

```
#include "mex.h"

void add_two_vectors(float *c, const float *a, const float *b, const size_t sz)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<sz; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // input validation
    if (nrhs != 2 || nlhs > 1) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Wrong number of input/output arguments.");
    }
    if (!mxIsSingle(prhs[0]) || !mxIsSingle(prhs[1])) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Inputs must be single arrays.");
    }
    if (mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[1])) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Inputs must be real arrays.");
    }
    if (mxIsSparse(prhs[0]) || mxIsSparse(prhs[1])) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Inputs must be dense arrays.");
    }
    if (mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]) != mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[1])) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Inputs must have the same size.");
    }

    // create ouput array
    mwSize numel = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);
    mwSize ndims = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[0]);
    const mwSize *dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(ndims, dims, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);

    // get pointers to data
    float *c = (float*) mxGetData(plhs[0]);
    float *a = (float*) mxGetData(prhs[0]);
    float *b = (float*) mxGetData(prhs[1]);

    // perform addition: c = a + b
    add_two_vectors(c, a, b, numel);
}
```

The function expects two arrays of type `single` of the same size (but can be of any dimensions including scalars, vectors, matrices, N-D arrays).

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims add_vectors.cpp
>> add_vectors(rand(4,'single'),rand(4,'single'))
ans =
    0.6204    1.2307    1.1657    0.7583
    1.3147    0.3817    0.3059    1.0377
    0.8142    0.3519    0.8619    1.1154
    1.0403    1.1578    0.1365    1.0048
```

Comment: By the way the function I use to add two vectors I borrowed from the CUDA SDK 5.5 and it works perfectly even for n-mode arrays :)

Comment: @darkmoor: yes I recall you had a question about CUDA+MEX but was deleted.. I was going to show this example there along with the adding kernel and a wrapper function around it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just static cast the output of `mxGetPr` (a `double*`) to a `float*` without misinterpreting the data.  Read in the contents as double and convert each element, not the pointer.

Alternatively, you can input a float array with `single(...)` on the input in MATLAB, and use `(float *)mxGetData` instead of `mxGetPr`.